# how to use the word "karaoke"

Tags: word-usage

According to dictionaries **karaoke** is an activity in which people sing a song while a karaoke machine plays the music.As we know in some of the books especially for kids after each song there's a part called as karaoke If we want to ask them wether they want to sing along to the karaoke or not is it wrong to say:

> 1) Do you want to sing with the karaoke or without the karaoke?
>
> 2) Do you want to sing with the karaoke **song** or without the karaoke **song**?
>
> 3) Do you want to sing with the karaoke **version** or without the karaoke **version**?

Comment: I wouldn't use any of those: I would say "with or without the **backing**". But if I had to use one, I think I'd choose no 1).

Comment: As an activity for children, I wouldn't use *karaoke*. "sing along with the music" or such would be better. Unless something has changed in recent times, *karaoke* usually refers to an adult activity.

Comment: Also did you check the dictionary definitions? In 1) you can't use it as a bare noun other than referring to the activity itself. 2) and 3) as a modifier it is OK, but 2) is incorrect because it doesn't define a song, just how you perform it.

Comment: @user3169 well actually the track's name is karaoke as well .what about saying karaoke or no karaoke is it ok?!

Comment: @user3169 and as you said I can use" with the karaoke version or with out the karaoke version" too.Does it sound natural?what about ''with the karaoke track"?

Comment: ''with the karaoke track" is better.